# Can't install CiviCRM on Joomla

Tags: joomla, installation

I can't install the CiviCRM onto my Joomla.  When trying to install it looks like it's working then it goes back to the install screen and nothing is installed.  I have tried the zip file and tmp folder.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Could you edit your question to provide a bit more information?  This will help people to help you.  E.g. which version of CiviCRM and Joomla are you using? What steps have you taken?  When does it fail?  What is your hosting environment?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the update database action, but it sounds like you might be installing a bad package or timing out. Could you share a screenshot? I might not be able to help much tonight, but I'd be happy to help you later this week if you don't have it resolved by then.

Comment: Where should I run the update database action? Can it be run from the command line?  I create an empty database, install joomla and then CiviCRM which fails to complete.